# Unable to resolve "./components/connect" from "node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

I have initialized a new `react-native` app using `expo-cli`.

After installing few dependencies, I got this error on build:

```
Unable to resolve "./components/connect" from "node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js"
```

Here is my `package.json` file.

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "firebase": "^5.10.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix this issue by downgrading `react-redux` to version `^4.4.10`